# why i can't use django admin app's resource

Tags: python, css, django, svg

i want to reuse django's contrib "admin" resource in my project, "admin" has a static directory, which is "static/admin/image/selector-icons.svg" i want to reuse.

i have such settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

i also tried:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static'),
    file path of admin's static
)
```

failed again.

"admin" can use "static/admin/image/selector-icons.svg" in its "widgets.css" like

```
.selector-add {
    background: url(../img/selector-icons.svg) 0 -96px no-repeat;
    cursor: default;
}
```

but i cant do like that in my project like this:

```
.selector-add {
    background: url(admin/img/selector-icons.svg) 0 -96px no-repeat;
    cursor: default;
}
```

console of chrome said 404 error! but

```
.selector-add {
    background: url(admin/img/selector-icons.gif) 0 -96px no-repeat;
    cursor: default;
}
```

worked.

and i find in "admin" render to html, "selector-icons.svg" will be transform to "selector-icons.gif", just like below picture:
[image: in red circle the css shows "selector-icons.gif", not "selector-icons.csv"]

so my question is:

first: how to reuse "admin" resource?

second:why "selector-icons.svg" to "selector-icons.svg"?

Comment: You don't have to add *file path of admin's static* to `STATICFILES_DIRS`, it will be found by the `AppDirectoriesFinder` as long as the admin app is in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, i think so, i just try.

Answer (score 1):

The icons have been changed from to svg in Django 1.9, which hasn't been released yet (see [ticket 20597](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20597)).

On older versions of Django, including the current release 1.8, the icons are gifs.

You could either use the gifs until you upgrade, or if you really need the svgs now, you could clone the repository and add [the svgs](https://github.com/django/django/tree/1.9a1/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img) to your static files.

Comment: oh, i think you misunderstand my problem, my django version is 1.8.4, and it's already having those svgs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Django 1.8.4 does not have the svg icons. Look at the [images directory](https://github.com/django/django/tree/1.8.4/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img) on GitHub.

Comment: oh thank u, i find my mistake, i read 1.9's source code and i develop in 1.8.4, thank u!!!!